# xml parse node in order if field missing

Tags: xml, scala

In Scala, I am trying to return the values of `appid` and `playtime_forever` for each message. I am getting the values, but they are not separated by a colon

My goal is to return strings like this `240:7110:99` and `103:104:NA` and `NA:4:NA`

```
<response>
    <game_count>120</game_count>
    <games>
        <message>
            <appid>240</appid>
            <playtime_forever>103</playtime_forever>
        </message>
        <message>
            <appid>7110</appid>
            <playtime_forever>104</playtime_forever>
            <playtime_2weeks>4</playtime_2weeks>
        </message>
        <message>
            <appid>99</appid>
        </message>
        ....
```

I tried to do it like this, but my code doesnt print the `:` between values.

```
 import scala.xml._
 import collection.mutable.HashMap
 import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
 import java.io.IOException
import java.io.FileWriter

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
    val api="BLAH"
    val res:String="76561198036298569"
        try{
        var id=""
        var playtime_forever=""
        var url="http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key="+api+"&steamid="+res+"&format=xml"
            var str = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url.toString,"utf-8").mkString        
            var x=xml.XML.loadString(str)       
            var allNodes = x \\ "response" \\ "games"   
            println(allNodes)
            println("===")
            allNodes.foreach(n => {
                id+=((n\\ "message"\\ "appid").text.mkString+":")
                playtime_forever+=((n\\ "message"\\ "playtime_forever").text.mkString+":")
            })
            id=id.dropRight(1)
            playtime_forever=playtime_forever.dropRight(1)
            println(id)
            println("===")
            println(playtime_forever)
        }
        catch{
            case e:  IOException=> println("4.Bad page request (profile locked down)")
            println("NA")
        }
}}
```

My output:

```
===
2407110685068606900240024202430151201990022330223201739024720101306020603032380323903240041700451008190499004267022380709008980122101222047810387204778099810655604432032104020920917003953032703956098800109700200550981009820092800728505523015001510152
0153020129010545020434020676020488020912069802116002117401088002041006910692028050201280984001153202169102076507302085802126804952020071020510020579070100701107012076708870200510224300224920224940224540220440227860219740322330233250244770244850248390
23560020642024154024347026176026420026430026655026911025197029402020181031704030769027567026164032873037397034005034262034611023019065980:
1031047600150016310639462850435310320238051159473703808182726891233201693412054165342792324301751299015495132390460443873851954101720404392861016201162121001233019337963364406457370269616429320390000946410560047166321029080898705251113602444197828434
8011527577224275325600701902340:

===
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extract your sample xml code and put it in message.xml

```
  <response>
     <games>
      <message>
         <appid>240</appid>
         <playtime_forever>103</playtime_forever>
     </message>
     <message>
         <appid>7110</appid>
         <playtime_forever>104</playtime_forever>
         <playtime_2weeks>4</playtime_2weeks>
     </message>
     <message>
         <appid>99</appid>
     </message>
    </games>
```

And then solve the problem as following code.

```
 import scala.xml.{ NodeSeq, XML }
 object XmlPrint extends App {
    // change this line according to your situation
    val originalXML = XML.load(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("message.xml"))

    val messageNodes = originalXML \\ "games" \\ "message"
    val attrCollector = (List[String](), List[String](), List[String]())

    def getValueFromNode(node: NodeSeq, attrName: String) = {
        (node \ attrName).find(_.label == attrName).map(_.text).getOrElse("N/A")
    }

    //(List(240, 7110, 99),List(103, 104, N/A),List(N/A, 4, N/A))
    val (appIds, foreverTimes, twoWeeks) = messageNodes.map { messageNode =>
        (
            // here, assuming message node can  have at most three sub nodes
            // appid playtime_forever playtime_2weeks
            getValueFromNode(messageNode, "appid"),
            getValueFromNode(messageNode, "playtime_forever"),
            getValueFromNode(messageNode, "playtime_2weeks")
        )
    }.foldRight(attrCollector)({
        (elem, attrTuple) => {
            val (l1, l2, l3) = attrTuple
            (elem._1 :: l1, elem._2 :: l2, elem._3 :: l3)
        }
    })

    // 240:7110:99
    println(appIds.mkString(":"))
    // 103:104:N/A
    println(foreverTimes.mkString(":"))
    // N/A:4:N/A
    println(twoWeeks.mkString(":"))
}
```

Anyway, hope it what you want.

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you explain what the `.foldRight` does?

Comment: In the answer, foldRight is to convert List[(appId, playtime_forever, playtime_2weeks) ... ] to
(List(appId1, appId2, appId3), ...). Actually, foldLeft and foldRight are for the aggregation purpose in Scala. A simple example
List(1, 2, 3, 4).foldLeft(10)((acc, elem) => acc - elem) traverses the List element and invoke the anonymous function.
The simplified form for the process would be (((10 - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4. foldRight is exactly doing the accumulation in different aciton
like 1 - (2 -(3 - (4 - 10))). Just check foldLeft and foldRight in the Scala source code and you will get it better.